# Read line by line of a file in shell script where last line doesn't end with new line

Tags: file, shell, newline

I have a text file which contains the following lines:

```
7.3.0
12
```

I am using the below lines to read the content line by line

```
while read -r LINE; do
    if test $n -eq 1 
    then 
       var01=$LINE
    fi
    if test $n -eq 2 
    then 
       var02=$LINE
    fi
    n=`expr $n + 1`
done < <(tr -d '\r' < /mnt/Share/hpsum_build.txt)
```

the above code doesn't read 2nd line that is last line '12' which doesn't end with a new line. How to read the last line as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your text line doesn't have an ending newline then you can do this at start of your script to force a newline in it:

```
echo '' >> /mnt/Share/hpsum_build.txt
```

You can also call `dos2unix` utility to remove DOS's `\r` before `\n` from each line.